# How to call java file in android Application

Tags: android

I have created a simple .java file and I wanted to execute in android application

Comment: BTW your activities is .java too

Comment: Please explain it a little more. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this directly.

When you compile a java source file it is first complied into a .class file which is Java byte code. After that the class files are then compiled again into a .dex file which is the Dalvik byte code which the Dalvik virtual machine can run. This .dex file is then compressed into an .apk file which is the archive which contain all your application's data. You can read more about it [here](http://www.itbusinessedge.com/).

Comment: oh ok, and Suppose I created java to jar file, then can I use and import in my android application?

Comment: yes .jar files can be added to this

Comment: Actually I did a simple java program in eclipse which print "Hello java!!" in java and then imported to .jar file and same jar file I imported and configured to build path in android application where I have to use .jar and call it, pls can u give me a example with Android with jar file usage...